# Non-ionizing particle radiation

Tags: radiation

First of all: I'm new here so please forgive me if my question doesn't meet the standards of this community.

My question is as follows: Does there exist non-ionizing particle radiation?

I know that alpha and beta radiation are types of ionizing particle radiation but I've find any information on whether non-ionizing particle radiation exists or not.

Comment: For all practical purposes visible light and longer wavelengths are non-ionizing. I say for "all practical purposes" because the photoelectric effect is essentially an ionization phenomenon, it just doesn't matter for daily life. What does matter for daily life is that UV radiation already breaks chemical bonds which creates free radicals (somewhat of a chemical equivalent of a "free electron") and that has very bad health effects. Whether you want to think of something like low energy neutrons and neutrinos as "ionizing radiation" is up for grabs because of indirect effects.

Comment: @FlatterMann Thanks. The question was meant to be low level as it is for 9th grade students. I'll just tell them that non-ionizing particle radiation doesn't exist. :-)

Comment: It depends on what you define as the work function. If the work function is zero, then it doesn't exist. If you define it practically as "somewhere in the region of a fraction of an eV to tens of eV", which is how an experimentalist would think about it, then it does exist. We are not going to get electrons out of metals with an itty bit of AM radio... personally I would rather teach the kids something practical, like how to make an ionization chamber out of a can.

Comment: "I'll just tell them that non-ionizing particle radiation doesn't exist." Or why don't you just tell them you don't know the answer. It is OK to not know all the answers. Especially when the question is ill-defined, like in this case.

Comment: As some others have noted, it depends on what you mean by "particle." An electron is usually called "beta radiation" when it is moving fast enough to ionize atoms. Otherwise we just call it an "electron" and certainly one doesn't worry about all electrons being ionizing (they are not if they are slow enough).

Comment: Similarly, "alpha radiation" is just a Helium nucleus that is moving fast enough to ionize atoms. If it is slow we just call it a Helium nucleus, and in fact it will probably be a Helium atom since it wants to pick up electrons.

Comment: Similarly, "gamma radiation" is just a photon with enough enough energy to stimulate a nucleus (and also ionize an atom). If the energy of a photon is not high enough to stimulate a nucleus, but is high enough to ionize an atom, we usually call it a "hard x-ray." Less energetic photons might still be considered "particles" but would not necessarily be able to ionize an atom. E.g., very soft xray, visible light, etc. But as the energy of the photon decreases, so does it's "hardness," meaning it tends to be less well characterized as a particle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [microwave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave) radiation used to heat food is one type of non-ionizing radiation. In general any electromagnetic radiation with a photon energy less than about 10 electron volts is considered to be [non-ionizing radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-ionizing_radiation).  This boundary falls in the ultraviolet and very roughly corresponds to the amount of energy it typically takes to ionize an atom. For example, visible light, microwaves, and radio waves are non-ionizing, while hard ultraviolet, x-rays, and gamma rays are ionizing.

More generally, the answer depends on how you define "particle" and  "[radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation)". For example, [acoustic radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound) such as [sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound) or [ultrasound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasound) is non-ionizing, but "[phonons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon)" are usually considered to be "only" [quasiparticles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiparticle). (The distinction between [particle and quasiparticle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/306426/145491), however, depends on one's theoretical framework.)  [Cosmic background neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_neutrino_background) and [gravitational radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) are two types of non-ionizing radiation that permeate all of space (including human bodies). Neutrinos are definitely particles, but without an established quantum theory of gravity, [gravitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton) are only hypothetical.

[Neutron radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_radiation) does not directly ionize atoms, but is deadly because it induces ionizing radiation in the form of nuclei recoiling from neutron scattering, gamma rays from neutron excitation of nuclei, or alpha, beta, or gamma radiation from [neutron activation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_activation).